# Survival Horror and Boss Rush?

Tags: scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world

In the "how to play" section of the help and options screen, there is a page that depicts two "extra game modes", Survival Horror and Boss Rush. I expected the two modes to be on the start screen, but I cannot seem to find them. Are these two game modes only offered once the game is completed, or after a certain part of the story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the title screen, press DOWN, UP, RIGHT, DOWN, UP, RIGHT, DOWN, UP, RIGHT, RIGHT, RIGHT to unlock the "Extra Game Modes" part of the main menu. Source: http://m.ign.com/cheats/games/scott-pilgrim-vs-the-world-the-game-xbox-360-22133